# Process context switch: if and only if triggered by interrupt?

Tags: process, operating-system, interrupt, interrupt-handling, context-switch

How does a context switch between two processes happen?

Is the only way to make it happen by sending some kind of interrupt to the CPU or are there other ways by which such a context switch is (usually) 'implemented'?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch#When_to_switch?

Answer (score 1):

A process can also yield the cpu in a system service call or exception handler.